# Change the path of the credential profiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to read the credentials file from AWS repository. I'm using ubuntu. My creadentials file is located at `~/.aws`

> ```
>  credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
> ```

Arrived at this line, i got an exception.

> credential profiles file not found in the given path:
>   /usr/share/tomcat7/.aws/credentials"

So, how can i change the path of the credential profiles from `tomcat7/.aws/credentials` to `~/.aws` ?

Comment: Is this Java? There is a version of the ProfileCredentialsProvider constructor that takes an explicit config file path.

Comment: By the way, tomcat is running as user tomcat7 and looking in the home directory of that user. So it is technically looking in `~/.aws` for the user it is running as.